# Is AWE in SQL 2005 Ent needed on 2003 32-bit w/ 24GB?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a WS 2003 32-bit system running SQL Server 2005 Enterprise with 24GB of RAM.  The /PAE switch is enabled.  Can SQL now use the 24GB or does AWE need to be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable AWE and also grant the SQL Server Service account the "Lock pages in memory" privilege.

Useful Reading: [SQL Server 2005 awe and memory](http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2008/06/03/sql-server-2005-and-awe-memory/)

For more concise steps consult the books online documentation: [Enabling AWE Memory for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190673(SQL.90).aspx)

Hope this helps but let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version of Windows you're running. Standard Edition will only see 4Gb irrelevant how many switches you add. You need Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition for the /PAE switch to see the entire 24GB of RAM. See [Physical Memory Limits: Windows Server 2003](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778(VS.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2003).